# Tastypie relationship fields for more than 2 models

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, tastypie

I'm learning to write an API using tastypie for a Django project. I have following code in `models.py`:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserDeviceIds(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)  
    device_id = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.device_id

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    referral_code = models.CharField(max_length=8, unique=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.mal_rank)
```

And, I have following code in `api.py`:

```
class CreateUserProfileResource(ModelResource):
    user = fields.ForeignKey('users.api.CreateUserResource', 'user', full=True)
    class Meta:
        list_allowed_methods = ['get','post']
        always_return_data = True
        authorization = Authorization()
        authentication = Authentication()
        validation = CreateUserProfileValidation()
        resource_name = 'auth'
        queryset = UserProfile.objects.all()
    def hydrate(self, bundle):
        bundle.data["user"]['username'] = bundle.data.get('country_code') + bundle.data.get("user")['username']
        # Set a password automatically:
        raw_password = ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase) for i in range(8))
        u = User(username='dummy')
        u.set_password(raw_password)
        bundle.data["user"]['password'] = u.password
        return bundle

class CreateUserResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        authorization = Authorization()
        authentication = Authentication()
        always_return_data = True
        resource_name = 'user'
        queryset = User.objects.all()
        excludes = ['is_active', 'is_staff', 'is_superuser', 'date_joined', 'last_login']
```

When I send a `POST` request to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/auth` (i.e:

```
    curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"user": {"email":"a@b.com","username":"abcdef"}, "referral_code":"abc123"}' http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/auth
```

then a `User` and a `UserProfile` object is successfully created. But I would also like to create a `UserDeviceIds` object in the same endpoint. I have tried combination of different [Tastypie Relationship Fields](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/fields.html) but I can't create a `UserDeviceIds` object. Can someone please elaborate on Tastypie relationship fields with some sample code to make me understand how the relationships work in Django?

For instance, I edited my `CreateUserProfileResource` in `api.py` and added the following line:

```
    deviceid = fields.ForeignKey('users.api.CreateUserDeviceIdsResource', 'deviceid', full=True)
```

so that `CreateUserProfileResource` now looks like:

```
class CreateUserProfileResource(ModelResource):
    user = fields.ForeignKey('users.api.CreateUserResource', 'user', full=True)
    deviceid = fields.ForeignKey('users.api.CreateUserDeviceIdsResource', 'deviceid', full=True)
    class Meta:
        list_allowed_methods = ['get','post']
        ...
        ...
```

and added a new Resource for `UserDeviceIds` model:

```
class CreateUserDeviceIdsResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        authorization = Authorization()
        authentication = Authentication()
        always_return_data = True
        resource_name = 'deviceid'
        queryset = UserDeviceIds.objects.all()
```

and when I try to send a POST request:

```
    curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"user": {"email":"a@b.com","username":"abcdef"}, "referral_code":"abc123", "deviceid": {"device_id": "abc"}}' http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/auth
```

I get following error traceback:

```
    {"error_message": "null value in column \"user_id\" violates not-null constraint
    DETAIL:  Failing row contains (2, abc, def, ghi, null).
    ", "traceback": "Traceback (most recent call last):

      File \"/vagrant/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py\", line 65, in execute
        return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

    psycopg2.IntegrityError: null value in column \"user_id\" violates not-null constraint
    DETAIL:  Failing row contains (2, abc, def, ghi, null).

    The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File \"/vagrant/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py\", line 201, in wrapper
        response = callback(request, *args, **kwargs)
      File \"/vagrant/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py\", line 432, in dispatch_list
        return self.dispatch('list', request, **kwargs)
      File \"/vagrant/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py\", line 464, in dispatch
        response = method(request, **kwargs)
      File \"/vagrant/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py\", line 1340, in post_list
        updated_bundle = self.obj_create(bundle, **self.remove_api_resource_names(kwargs))
      File \"/vagrant/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py\", line 2104, in obj_create
        return self.save(bundle)
      File \"/vagrant/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py\", line 2247, in save
        self.save_related(bundle)
      File \"/vagrant/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py\", line 2318, in save_related
        related_resource.save(related_bundle)
      File \"/vagrant/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tastypie/resources.py\", line 2250, in save
        bundle.obj.save()
      File \"/vagrant/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py\", line 589, in save
        force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
      File \"/vagrant/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py\", line 617, in save_base
        updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
      File \"/vagrant/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py\", line 698, in _save_table
        result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)
      File \"/vagrant/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py\", line 731, in _do_insert
        using=using, raw=raw)
      File \"/vagrant/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py\", line 92, in manager_method
        return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
      File \"/vagrant/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py\", line 921, in _insert
        return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
      File \"/vagrant/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py\", line 920, in execute_sql
        cursor.execute(sql, params)
      File \"/vagrant/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py\", line 81, in execute
        return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
      File \"/vagrant/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py\", line 65, in execute
        return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
      File \"/vagrant/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/utils.py\", line 94, in __exit__
        six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
      File \"/vagrant/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/six.py\", line 658, in reraise
        raise value.with_traceback(tb)
      File \"/vagrant/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py\", line 65, in execute
        return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
    django.db.utils.IntegrityError: null value in column \"user_id\" violates not-null constraint
    DETAIL:  Failing row contains (2, abc, def, ghi, null).
    "}
```

which I understand means that when it tried to save a UserDeviceIds object, it could not find data in bundle to put in the `ForeignKey(User)` field of `UserDeviceIds` model.

Can someone explain what needs to be done to make this code work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can't achieve it in current relation. The model resources are true reflection of models. For instance you could create this:

```
>>> UserProfile.objects.create(refferal_code='asdfasdf', user=User.objects.create_user(username='asdfasdf'))
```

or this:

```
>>> UserDeviceIds.objects.create(device_id='adfadf', user=User.objects.create_user(username='asdfasdfas'))
```

But not both in one instruction.

The REST API is great because it quite well feet Django ORM own interface.

So you can create object with children but not with other parents at the same time.

You have named your Resources with functional purpose `creation` that clearly suggest something is not right. Your Resource should be assign only to model.

In my own opinion REST API is great for working with, because it's clear, easy to understand for clients, easy rules, fast to build, easy to test. But doesn't feet really well sign-up with Django.

If you will have to break some RESTful rules don't try to redefine existing fully functioning Resources it can give a lot of pain. Instead Make some custom separated endpoint well described for this purpose.

I suggest to create custom view like endpoint handling json/xml whatever you support for sign-up. Hold it in separated app if you find better solution in future you will easily replace it. I suggest it because: 1. It's critical for you to create these 3 models in one call, it will break models if internet gets off. 2. Will be faster.

I doubt in existence of the ready apps solving the problem because sing-up is always bit unique for each website.

```
import json

from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.http import (HttpResponse, HttpResponseBadRequest,
                         HttpResponseNotAllowed)
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt


@csrf_exempt
def signup(request):
    """
    Description:
    POST faldksfalskdfjalksdf

    Headers:
    sdfasdf

    Attributes:
    sadljfkasdlfksad

    Responses:
    asdf
    """
    if request.method != 'POST':
        return HttpResponseNotAllowed(permitted_methods=('POST',))
    try:
        data = json.loads(request.body)
    except (AttributeError, ValueError):
        return HttpResponseBadRequest(
            json.dumps({'error': 'JSON format invalid',
                        'success': False}),
            content_type='application/json')


    if data.get('username', None) and data.get('device_id', None) and data.get('country', None):
        # add more validation.
        user = User.objects.create_user(username=data['username'])
        UserProfile.objects.create(refferal_code='asdfasdf', user=user)
        UserDeviceIds.objects.create(device_id='adfadf', user=user)
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'success': True}),
                            content_type='application/json')

    else:
        return HttpResponseBadRequest(
            json.dumps({'error': 'username, device_id or country attributes missing.',
                        'success': False}),
            content_type='application/json')
```

Comment: I get your point.What if I make a resource for `User` model and then `UserProfile` and `UserDeviceIds` would be children and so I should be able to create objects of these children models... Right? Can you please elaborate as to what would be downsides of this approach?

Comment: You could do and it would work in one call, but you have to change model relations in order to change resource relations. The downside is that you are making application interface dictator of your database architecture. You can lost db efficiency and over-complicate other models or other operations.